# Downvote because he did not understand the question like me

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason

I tried to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874202/json-javascript-get-array-values)

It was not very clear but I thought that I understood the question and then post [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39874304/4245446)

Someone else gave [a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39874441/4245446) few minutes later

Both of us got a downvote and rude comments from @Rajesh which is absolutely sure that **HE** correctly understood the question and that both me and @Nina Sholz did not.

Given that the question is totally not clear but some propositions can be made, is it acceptable to downvote "correct" answers ?

Comment: It is totally not clear but you are sure of all these things. Hmm

Comment: The question is not clear but I think that I have understand the idea of OP. I may be wrong but want to help OP

Comment: @Weedoze If you want to help the OP then help them clarify their question into something that's understandable, rather than posting guesses that are likely to be wrong.  If you post an answer *after the question has been clarified* then you would actually be being helpful.

Comment: Of course you do want to help the op, but also yourself, which is why you are willing to, in blind faith, throw spaghetti at the wall and pray. Have you picked up on the trend that bad questions are typically only answered by people with under 100 or 200 rep?

Comment: @Weedoze Another bad thing about answering questions that doesn't meet Stack Overflow's standard is that it sends the message to new and "old" users that poor / no research / code dump / what ever questions will get a answer regardless of how bad their question is. - Which leads to more bad questions getting posted.

Comment: not clear refine your question

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is exactly why you shouldn't answer unclear questions, you should vote to close them as unclear until the author clarifies them, and comment if/when you feel you can help guide the author into asking a clearer question.  It's *entirely* appropriate for someone to downvote an answer because they feel it doesn't correctly answer what they feel the question is asking, and that's *much* more likely to happen when you answer unclear questions, *which is why you shouldn't*.

Comment: Seems legit. I was just trying to help OP